# Doesn't Stack Overflow Jobs return anything?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I'm not sure if this is the right forum, but I just noticed that **Stack Overflow Jobs** advertise in a way indicating that searching for a job there won't ***return*** anything?

[image: Stack Overflow Jobs ad]

*Also, the comment at the end breaks the code, but who's **that** picky about an ad...*

Comment: Clearly you're bored, so by the ad's logic, shouldn't you be searching for a  new job? :)

Comment: Ouch, downvoted. I guess `someDevs.lackHumor()`.

Comment: You want to *cause* some devs to lack humour? You monster! (Unless `lackHumor()` is a getter, in which case I shall berate you for your naming conventions

Comment: `any(dev.lacks_humor for dev in all_devs)` 

Comment: @Pekka I just tried to adhere to the design principles put forth in the ad. :)

Comment: @Ted BURN -------

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: Answer to this question is simple, no one knows what is the actual code used in the ad so if it is anything like ruby, omitting the "return" is actually preferred. However, it could also be that searchJobs starts an infinite loop as we should always check what else is there available.. ;>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Stevie](https://twitter.com/consumetea) and I worked on the copy for that ad. I'm ashamed to say that I failed to adhere to [the Command-Query Separation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation): `searchJobs` both performs the search and displays the jobs on the screen.

To prevent issues like this from occurring in the future, we're going to introduce a comprehensive review system for fictitious pseudocode. Next time you see code in an ad, it will have been through a six-month process of planning and architecture, approved by senior management, and consecrated to Saint Dijkstra.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive and informative answer, I shall accept it immediately! The proposed process going forward sounds excellent. :)

Comment: Six months is ridiculous, that could easily be achieved in only 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Will each ad have a test suite of its own?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in your assertion that "Stack Overflow Jobs" doesn't return anything. Nothing physical, at least.

Naturally, `searchJobs` calls `renderJobs`, which displays the search results found in `searchJobs`.

Comment: And in case someone comes complaining that this is impure code -- that's okay. Job search shouldn't be free of side effects. Switching jobs is a change of global state.

Comment: While I think `searchJobs` is a misleading name if it in fact results in rendering, it would explain why there's no need for a return value while still helping devs find new jobs. Thanks! :)